# Processing Java, how to show/hide bar chart by pressing a button?

Tags: java, processing

I'm doing this code to draw bar chart by pressing button and it works. But I want the bar chart to be hidden again if I pressed on the same button.

### Kindly, Could you please help me with that ?

this is my code inside the button:

```
if (mousePressed) 
  { // film 1

    if (( mouseX > 1150) && (mouseY > 38) && (mouseX < 1207) && (mouseY < 65))
    {
      int x=0;
      text("Rank    Country    Film",25,10);
      int tRows = table1.getRowCount();

      for(int i = 0; i < tRows; i++)
      {
        TableRow row = table1.getRow(i);
        String r1 = row.getString("film");
        String r2 = row.getString("country");
        float r3 = row.getFloat("boxoffice");
        int r4 = row.getInt("rank");

        fill(255,0,0);
        pushMatrix();
        translate (0,25);
        int legendXOffset = 20;
        textFont(f,9);

        text(r4,legendXOffset,i*11);
        text(r2,legendXOffset + 20,i*11);
        text(r1,legendXOffset + 70,i*11);
        popMatrix();

        float h = map(r3, 15, 0, 0, 80);
        // change this one oamr x+30, x+=20 to make bars sepretly
        rect(x+29, 635, 7, h);
        x+=50;
        int rank = row.getInt("rank");
        String film = row.getString("film");
        String country = row.getString("country");

      }
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more code to help you. The way this part of the code is lead me to guess you are not using a call to `background(someColor)` inside your draw, right?

I think the way to go is:

- Use the callBack function `mousePressed()` instead of the field `mousePressed`. This is going to give you a better control
- Use a boolean as a flag to draw or not the bar graph. Toggle this flag when the button is pressed.
- in `draw()` clear the bg using `background()`
- Yet in `draw()` conditionally draw the graph.

Here an example using a simple rect as a placeholder for the graph:

```java
// CLICK THE SCREEN TO SHOW THE "GRAPH"

boolean showGraph = false;


void setup(){
  size(300,300);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  background(255);
}


void draw(){
  //clear bg
  background(255);

  //conditionally draw
  if(showGraph){
    drawGraph();
  }
}


void mousePressed(){
  showGraph = !showGraph; // toggles true or false
}


void drawGraph(){
  fill(200,23,178);
  rect(width/2, height/2, 100,88);
}
```

Comment: I really thank you for replying me, this is my code, it worked with the first button but the other no.

Comment: This is all your code? I don't think so. I believe the problem is not in this piece of code but in the whole structure.